# Post to folder under a public S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, permissions, acl

I can successfully post a file object via AJAX in client javascript code from my browser to the *ROOT* of an s3bucket, using this code:

```
function upload_file(path, fileObj) {
 var fd = new FormData();
 fd.append('key', fileObj.name);
 fd.append('acl', 'bucket-owner-full-control');
 fd.append('Content-Type', fileObj.type);
 fd.append("file",fileObj);

 return $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : path,
    data : fd,
    processData: false,  // Don't process the data
    contentType: false,  // Don't set contentType
    success: function(json) { console.log('Upload complete!') },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Upload error: ' + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    }
 });
}
```

The destination is a test-only temporary(!) globally public S3 bucket configured as follows:

[image: public settings]

[image: acl]

[image: bucket policy]

[image: cors]

My problem is that I cannot post to any folder below the root of this bucket. Concretely put, doing this...

```
upload_file('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket.example.com/', fileObj)
```

results in a successful upload to root bucket.

However doing this...

```
upload_file('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket.example.com/sounds/', fileObj)
```

returns this error from S3:

```
Upload error: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
<Code>MethodNotAllowed</Code>
<Message>The specified method is not allowed against this resource.</Message>
<Method>POST</Method> 
<ResourceType>OBJECT</ResourceType> 
<RequestId>DC6AA872FC4F96B4</RequestId>
<HostId>/AOtAuVcXnRZrQD7Rs+EmpZ2H5YDs5TPgEjmvMpVqSdZuPbnTtE/nh4p/Fgad8v00VQ93RKer8g=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Since only posting to the subfolder is the problem, I assume my code is correct and that I have misconfigured my folder. What am I missing? My intent after overcoming this problem is to proceed to a more traditional pre-signed URL approach, but still wanted to get the bucket permissions sorted first.

Comment: Are the subfolder permissions the same?

Comment: I cannot see how to permission folders directly, Nick, and have not permissioned the folder beyond simply creating it with defaults. But I did select the folder afterwards, and via Actions made it public, just for good measure. Does one have to *recreate* folders after changing the bucket permissions/cors/acls?

Comment: Just blew away the subfolder and recreated it with the defaults (and it states that the folder inherits the same settings from bucket). Still get the same error when I try to post to it. Made it public again. Same error.

Comment: Your CORS configuration is correct and the error message cited in the question isn’t related to CORS. If you were having a CORS problem, you’d be getting an error message from the browser on the client side. But instead you’re getting a server-side error message. So it seems the solution the problem needs to found somewhere other than in your CORS configuration.

Comment: I am counting on that as well. But just in case, wanted to give that config so that others wouldn't ask for it. Thanks, sideshowbarker. Do you see any issues with the other configuration?

Comment: If I change the verb from POST to PUT, I get totally different behavior: upload_file('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket.example.com//', fileObj) gives a new error: "The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema", and upload_file('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket.example.com/sounds//', fileObj) throws no error, but the upload doesnt succeed. wtf amazon! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 fd.append('key', fileObj.name);
```

The object key is were you specify the full path to the file, without a leading slash.  The only thing that needs to be different is this line:

```
fd.append('key', 'sounds/' + fileObj.name);
```